# Bitbucket 502 on Push

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a mercurial repository which halfway trough a 93meg push to bitbucket suddenly stops with a 502 bad gateway error.

IS there anyway I can get some more diagnostic information.  This has had me stumped for days!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your internet connection. Maybe a misconfigured proxy is changing Mercurial’s HTTP requests? Could be on the side of your ISP, or somewhere in your company gateway. (e.g. I know on KPN mobile internet their proxy kills "DELETE" requests. That’s horrible, yes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a great answer, but switching from HTTP to SSH might solve your problem.
(It did for me.)

See here for instructions:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Comment: For me the symptom was that after thinking for a while during a push, TotroiseHG gave up with an   abort: error: ''.   Switching to SSH fixed it.